# Simple Remote Shared Object with Red5 Flash Server

Tags: java, actionscript-3, red5, shared-objects

I am trying to create a simple chat client using the red5 media server, but I seem to be having a slight hiccup. I am creating a shared object on the server side, and it seems to be creating it successfully. However, when I make changes to the object via the client (type a message), the SYNC event fires, but the content within the shared object remains empty. I suspect I am doing something wrong on the java end, any advice?

**Console Results:**

```
Success!

Server Message: clear

Server Message: [object Object]

Local message: asdf

Server Message: change

Server Message: [object Object]

Local message: fdsa

Server Message: change

Server Message: [object Object]

Local message: fewa

Server Message: change

Server Message: [object Object]
```

**Server Side:**

```
    package org.red5.core;

import java.util.List;

import org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter;
import org.red5.server.api.IConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.IScope;
import org.red5.server.api.service.ServiceUtils;
import org.red5.server.api.so.ISharedObject;
// import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
// import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class Application extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private IScope appScope;
    // private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog( Application.class );

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public boolean connect(IConnection conn, IScope scope, Object[] params) {

        appScope = scope;
        createSharedObject(appScope, "generalChat", false); // Creates general chat shared object

        return true;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void disconnect(IConnection conn, IScope scope) {
        super.disconnect(conn, scope);
    }  

    public void updateChat(Object[] params)
    {
        ISharedObject so = getSharedObject(appScope, "generalChat"); // Declares and stores general chat data in general chat shared object
        so.setAttribute("point", params[0].toString());
    } 
}
```

**Client Side:**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*; 


    // This class is going to handle all data to and from from media server
    public class SOConnect extends MovieClip
    {
        // Variables
        var nc:NetConnection = null;
        var so:SharedObject;        
        public function SOConnect():void
        {
        }   
        public function connect():void
        {       
            // Create a NetConnection and connect to red5
            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
            nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/testChat");

            // Create a StoredObject for general chat
            so = SharedObject.getRemote("generalChat", nc.uri, false);          
            so.connect(nc);
            so.addEventListener(SyncEvent.SYNC, receiveChat)            
        }

        public function sendChat(msg:String)
        {
            trace ("Local message: " + msg);
            nc.call("updateChat", null, msg)                    
        }


        public function receiveChat(e:SyncEvent):void
        {           
            for (var i in e.changeList)
            {
                trace ("Server Message: " + e.changeList[i].code)
                trace ("Server Message: " + e.changeList[i])
            }                       
        }

        // Given result, determine successful connection        
        private function netStatusHandler(e:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
            if (e.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success")
            {
                trace("Success!");
            }
            else 
            {
                trace("Failure!\n");    
                trace(e.info.code);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that the red5 simple chat doesn't require server side script, just like video streaming

Comment: The red5 shared object tutorial is on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MuLnMKYe9k&playnext=1&list=PL310F0481BCE4D194&feature=results_main

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need to write anything on the server side in order to do a chat in as3 and red5;

here is an example for you [the chat that it is working and it is written in as3/flex3](http://dev.binertia.com/chat.mxml)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its posible to create a chat without writing server side code but i dont see how someone could control users disconnections or use lists of users on sync, anyway back to the subject maybe you have a problem with dir permissions so try running red5 as root/admin once , just to check if it works, if it does you should create a user (with the correct writing permissions) in your system and then run red5 using that user.