# Can you store SharedObjects in the cloud

Tags: actionscript-3, cloud

I'm pretty sure this can be done, but I'm honestly not sure where to begin. I've looked for tutorial after tutorial but still no use.I have a cloud host, I know my Actionscript, My PHP and everything.If somebody could just point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? SharedObjects are limited in size.

Comment: I know, it's just I want to have small sharedobjects but retrievable from different devices from the same account.Cross platform SharedObjects.

Comment: So do you have any method?

Comment: I'd say store user data via normal SQL DBs, and let your SWF log in to the server and retrieve whatever data they have stored via a PHP/XML request.

Comment: Yes, but they also create data that has to be stored within the Flash app itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can: "Shared objects offer real-time data sharing between multiple client SWF files and objects that are persistent on the local computer or remote server. Local shared objects are similar to browser cookies and remote shared objects are similar to real-time data transfer devices. To use remote shared objects, you need Adobe Flash Media Server."  (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html)

How you do this on Adobe Flash Media Server 4.5: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d37a-7ffaDev.html

or Red5: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MuLnMKYe9k&feature=share&list=PL310F0481BCE4D194

and [Simple Remote Shared Object with Red5 Flash Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546479/simple-remote-shared-object-with-red5-flash-server)

Comment: Thank you so much! After reading into it, is there any other way of sending data to the cloud from Flash rather than PHP.With the SharedObjects, the registration/login system was used in sharedobjects too, but when I choose the data for my specific account, how does it know which data to send to which specific account?

Comment: Sorry if I make it sound complicated, what I mean is: If I change the username SharedObjects, the sharedobjects that I created using the first username are the same, how do I make it as though when I change the account I log in to on the same computer that the data with the old account changes to the data for the new account, but if I login to the old account again that it will retrieve the old data. In other words: How do I make specific sharedobject for a specific sharedobject if that makes sense?